# Don't collapse today's achievement list when opening the reputation tab

Tags: bug, status-completed, top-bar, achievements-dialog

I like using multiple tabs. I especially like keeping the questions tab open on Meta, opening any other links in new tabs.

The achievements drop-down has a link to my reputation tab:

[image: links!]

Each site icon with daily delta is a link to the reputation tab for your account on that site. But when I use <kbd>⌘</kbd>-click (Command click, this is a Mac) to open the link in a new tab, the 'today' section is simultaneously collapsed:

[image: oi, my links!]

Could the section collapse / expand toggle link be altered to *not* include the per-site reputation links? It should be limited to the `Today ▾` and `Yesterday ▾` links only.

Comment: Oh yeah that's crap, fixing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build, those weren't an intended click target area for the collapse.

Comment: \o/ Thanks for the fix. :-)